# How to redirect from one component to other component in lightning?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, lightning-experience, lightning-design-system, lightning-connect

I want this when user click it is got account id and with id it is redirect to `AccountDetailLightning`.

This my first component:

```
`<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="link"  aura:id="{!obj.Id}" onclick="{!c.RedirectToSupplierDeatilsPage}">
        <!--    <ui:button href="javascript:void(0);" class="link" press="{!c.RedirectToSupplierDeatilsPage}" > -->
                <h3 class="title" >{!obj.Name}</h3>
                <span>Address:</span> <span >{!obj.BillingStreet}</span>
                <span >Phone:</span> <span >{!obj.Phone}</span>
                <span>Customer Number:</span> <span >{!obj.AccountNumber}</span>

            </a>
```

js controler code.

```
RedirectToSupplierDeatilsPage:function(component,event,helper)
    { debbuger;
        var evt = $A.get("e.c:AccountDetailLightning");
        evt.setParams({ "obj.Id": "00QB0000000ybNX"
      });
         navEvt.fire();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `force:navigateToComponent` event.

eg:-

```
navigateToRollCall : function(component, event, helper) {
var evt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToComponent");
    evt.setParams({
        "obj.Id": "00QB0000000ybNX"
    });
    evt.fire();    
}
```